# Android API Break

Tags: android, linux, sdk

I have installed android studio on Ubuntu there is an API with break images, I have tried reinstalling also. what should I do to overcome this problem.

[image]

After deleting it the package it is not showing in sdk manager

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: select and delete it then download again.

Comment: After deleting from where should I download it is not showing in the android sdk manager to download

Comment: when you delete it SDK manager refresh automatically then you will find  `Intelx86` under Extras. just select it and install

Comment: Please check the image I have added after deleted

Comment: i answered your question u can check it

Answer (score 2):

First select and delete `Intel x86 Atom` or `your broken api` and `Atom google api` or `your broken google api` from sdk manager.

then download that Intel x86 Atom and Atom google api or other images as follows

1- open **Sdk Manager**   //if already open ignore it

2- GO to your android version or api level

3 - Under your Android version or API level Select image that you need

4 - select and install

[image: LIke this]

i hope this work for you