# HAXM Installer not compatible 6.0.5

Tags: android, android-studio

I already install intel haxm 6.1.0 but why i can't still install this on android studio anyone can help me with this problem.. Ty !!!
[this is my SDK Manager showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YBqJ.png)

Comment: follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818783/andorid-api-break?noredirect=1#comment70825956_41818783

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try downloading HAXM from the source at https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
You should also check to see if your processor supports Intel Virtualization. If it does, check your Bios and make sure that Intel Virtualizer is switched on.

This link will help you determine if your processor supports it.
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005486.html