# My android studio isn't showing the preview and also the HAXM installer isn't working?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-studio-2.1, haxm

I am using the android studio for the **first time** but when I open it, I can't find the **preview window**. I have tried many thing but I can't even **check** it from the view button and the windows tools.
The other problem that the **HAXM** installer is installed and I have enabled it from the **BIOS** but in the **SDK manager tools** is still showing the message ***"Not compatible with windows"*** however When I run a virtual phone from the **AVD Manager** it works. **PLEASE HELP!**

[Screenshot for my android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAP8V.png)

[Screenshot for the SDK Manager tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGqIY.png)

Comment: your probably have to select the `layout` from the project tab located at the left side fo the screen.

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818783/andorid-api-break/41819103#41819103 for setting up your sdk

Comment: I Can't find the layout on the project tab.

Answer (score 0):

For preview you must open a **layout or .XML** file as only .XML can be previewed.
To open a layout go to **res->layout** folder in **Project** tab

For the HAXM installation, chk this out

[The intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) revision 6.0.5 is showing not compatible with windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092207/the-intel-x86-emulator-accelerator-haxm-installer-revision-6-0-5-is-showing-no)

Comment: I can't find Anything called res or layout in the project tab.
and for the HAXM, it doesn't works too, it still shows that message.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your effort. It worked :) .

Comment: But There is still the problem of Emulator accelerator (HAXM installer)

Comment: did you checked the link

Comment: I checked it and the emulator is working but in the sdk tools I still see the message.